# Laravel-api for multiple file upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to make laravel api for multiple file upload when i am uploading then its gives error $data is undefined variable.please help me how to remove this error..?

**FileUploadController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Detail;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class FileUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadFile(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [

        'user_sharing_image' => 'required',

        'user_sharing_image.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip'

        ]);

        if($request->hasfile('user_sharing_image'))

         {
            foreach($request->file('user_sharing_image') as $file)

            {
                $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();

                $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);  

                $data[] = $name;  
            }
         }

         $file= new Detail();
         $file->title = $request->title;
         $file->info = $request->info;
         $file->user_id = $request->user()->id;
         $file->user_sharing_image=json_encode($data);

         $file->save();

        return back()->with('success', 'Data Your files has been successfully added');
    }
}
```

I am using laravel passport for auth and want to store user_id but do not geting please help me how to resolve both problem from this code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it a try

```
$data = [];
if($request->hasfile('user_sharing_image'))
 {
    foreach($request->file('user_sharing_image') as $key=>$file)

    {
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();    
        $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);      
        $data[$key] = $name;  
    }
 }

 $file= new Detail();
 $file->title = $request->title;
 $file->info = $request->info;
 $file->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
 $file->user_sharing_image=json_encode($data);

 $file->save();
```

Comment: this is my route Route::post('file-upload', 'API\FileUploadController@uploadFile'); when hit the api the its gives login page in postman

Comment: if you want to get auth data using Auth::user(), you need to use passport package. follow https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport. Otherwise pass user_id in your request data.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `$data` is not defined.

Before `foreach` loop you can declare it as `$data =  array();`

Comment: its gives error Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

**Hello fellow developers**

**This will work properly**

```
 $files = $request->allFiles('imgs');

            foreach ($files as $key => $img) {
                # code...
                $filename = request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . '/assets/images/users/upload/profile/photos/' . time() . '.'. $img->extension();
                $img->move(public_path('/assets/images/users/upload/profile/photos/'), $filename);


                $photos = UserPhoto::create([
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'name' => $filename
                ]);
            }


            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'data' => 'Photos Uploaded Successfully!!'
            ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you should use files method to return array of files :

```
     foreach($request->files('user_sharing_image') as $file)
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException: Method App\Http\Requests\DamageReportRequest::files does not exist

Please make sure files is correct